# Python : How to read file timestamp which is in html page in python

Tags: python, html, timestamp, zip

I have a zipfile in html page, Is there any way to read that file's create\modified timestamp in python.  I know we can read timestamp if it is in local directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no way to know about the file's timestamp unless the web page gives it to you. Sometimes you can read the file's parent container and get an index page for all of its files, but most public web servers try to block that sort of thing.

Comment: the timestamp details are visible on the html page. the page contains file name and its last modified timestamp value. so how can i read that value.

Comment: There are many ways to read/parse/extract data from a web page. A good option is to use `urllib2` or `requests` to fetch the page and `BeautifulSoup` or the BeautifulSoup parser in `lxml` to load the page into python. Then you look at the source text and use one of the xml functions or xpath to grab it. You search for examples and take a stab at it. If it doesn't work, you've got a new more detailed question you can post to stackoverflow.